# How to read a text file blocks with breaks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, recursion

I have a text file with paper title and links such as:

```
Federated Learning for Healthcare Informatics1
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7659898/

AI in Health: State of the Art, Challenges, and Future Directions
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/pmid/31419814/

Artificial Intelligence in Primary Health Care: Perceptions, Issues, and Challenges
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6697547/

Systematic Review of Privacy-Preserving Distributed Machine Learning From Federated Databases in Health Care
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7113079/

Privacy-first health research with federated learning
https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.12.22.20245407v1.full-text

Federated Learning of Electronic Health Records Improves Mortality Prediction in Patients Hospitalized with COVID-19
https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.08.11.20172809v1.full-text

Patch-Based Surface Morphometry Feature Selection with Federated Group Lasso Regression
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7694696/
```

I want to convert this file into a data frame with two columns: title and links

I have tried a recursive solution to read such file:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    raw_file = [k.strip() for k in f.readlines()]
    

global_store = []

def extract_data(list_l):
    temp_store = []
    for line in range(len(list_l)):
        
        if list_l[line]=='':
            global_store.append(temp_store)
            return extract_data(list_l[line+1:])
        else:
            temp_store.append(list_l[line])
    global_store.append(temp_store)
    
extract_data(raw_file)
```

later converting list of lists to df:

```
def convert2df(listoflist):
    
    df_records = {'title': [], 'links': []}
    
    for record in listoflist:
        df_records['title'].append(record[0])
        df_records['links'].append(record[1])
    return pd.DataFrame(df_records)
        
convert2df(global_store)
```

Is there any better method to replace the recursive solution?

Answer (score 1):

The groups are split by two consecutive new-line's, right? So you can split once on the double new-line, and again on the single new-line separating the Title and Link. E.g.

```
import pandas as pd

data = open('text_file.txt', 'r').read()
df = pd.DataFrame([line.split('\n') for line in data.split('\n\n')], columns=['Title', 'Link'])
```

Produces the following:
[image: Output]